# Domain level authentication of public API key with google calendar public calendars via PHP

Tags: php, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to rewrite a google calendar script to update to the API v3.

I would like to NOT force my users to authenticate their calendars one at a time with an oAuth 2 routine.  They should be able to set the calendars as public and not have to do this.  The goal of the script is to publicly display the calendar, so it shouldn't need complex authentication since the data is made public already anyways.

I can successfully do this using the API key that uses the server IP address.  But many users have shared hosting where their IP changes frequently.  I would prefer to have API keys based on the domain name instead.  Is this possible?

```
<?php    
// set to Public API access with IP address at
// https://console.developers.google.com/project/MYPROJECT/apiui/credential
// works
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/494h1li4bohjc380cl8bntq94k%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key=MYAPIKEY_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&maxResults=100&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=2014-11-18T14:00:00-00:00';

// set to Public API access with "Browser Key" and referer *.mydomainname.com/* 
// at https://console.developers.google.com/project/MYPROJECT/apiui/credential
// does not work  
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/494h1li4bohjc380cl8bntq94k%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key=MYAPIKEY_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&maxResults=100&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=2014-11-18T14:00:00-00:00';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the calendars are public then you should be able to authenticate as ANY Google account and read the calendar, you don't need to authenticate as that specific user. Use standard OAuth 2.0 authentication and request offline access so that you'll get a refresh token which can be used to refresh the access token.